# Input string was not in a correct format for radio button

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I had used 2 controls to edit gridview inside.It shows error "input string was not in a correct format"

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                fill_grd();
                fill_gender();
            }    
        }  

        public void fill_gender()
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Gender_get", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                radiolist.DataValueField = "Gid";
                radiolist.DataTextField = "Gname";
                radiolist.DataSource = ds;
                radiolist.DataBind();
            }

            con.Close();
        }

        public void fill_grd()
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Login_get", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                grd.DataSource = ds;
                grd.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {

                grd.DataSource = null;
                grd.DataBind();
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        protected void grd_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            grd.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            fill_grd();
        }

        protected void grd_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            int id = int.Parse(grd.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Login_delete", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lid", id);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            fill_grd();
        }

        protected void grd_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            TextBox TB1 = (TextBox)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("edittxtname");
            RadioButtonList RBL1 = (RadioButtonList)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("editradiolist");

            int id = int.Parse(grd.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Login_update", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lid", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TB1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", RBL1.SelectedValue);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            grd.EditIndex = -1;
            fill_grd();
        }

        protected void grd_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            grd.EditIndex = -1;
            fill_grd();
        }

        protected void savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Login_insert", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", int.Parse(radiolist.SelectedValue));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            fill_grd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code has nothing to do with radio buttons; please post the actual code that is producing that error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your error occurs and the code you've pasted is really not relevant for your question but I'll try to answer anyway.

You need to check the datatype for the radio button, it's probably not a bool or int. It seems you are setting datatypes from the results you get from the database and I would guess you need to change the datatype by checking the stored procudure usp_Login_get and the datatype you are setting for the radiobutton column.